# Python Scheduled Log Rotating

Tags: python, logging, rotation

EDIT:

Looks like other people are having a similar issue with `TimedRotatingFileHandler`.

[Python TimedRotatingFileHandler not rotating at midnight till something new is written to the log file. How to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601805/python-timedrotatingfilehandler-not-rotating-at-midnight-till-something-new-is-w)

[Why doesn't my TimedRotatingFileHandler rotate at midnight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496727/why-doesnt-my-timedrotatingfilehandler-rotate-at-midnight?rq=1)

Apparently, the logs don't rotate unless there is some activity happening in the logs. Is there a way I can achieve the scheduled rotating functionality I want using the builtin Handlers without having to create a custom rotator?

---

ORIGINAL POST:

I'm using the [`TimedRotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) of Python's `logging` module to rotate my logs regularly.

I've specified the configurations in logging.conf for my app's loggers and handlers as such:

```
[logger_worker]
level=DEBUG
propogate=0
qualname=worker
handlers=workerHandler

[handler_workerHandler]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=standardFormatter
args=("/var/log/app/worker.log","M",1,30,None,False,False)
```

- Note: for testing purposes I've configured the handler to rotate the logs on every minute, but ideally the logs will be rotated on a daily basis at midnight.

In my app, I am creating the logger like this:

```
logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf")
log = logging.getLogger("worker")

log.debug('Hello world')
```

It is not working as I expected it to work:

1. It is not rotating all the logs
2. It is not rotating every minute as it is configured to do

Observe the `ls -l` output of the log directory:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       0 Apr 19 18:22 dpv.log
-rw-r----- 1 root root    5092 Apr 20 11:47 emperor.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   88939 Apr 20 11:47 uwsgi.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     494 Apr 20 11:46 worker.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   45906 Apr 20 02:08 worker.log.2016-04-20_02-08
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     494 Apr 20 11:34 worker.log.2016-04-20_11-34
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     494 Apr 20 11:36 worker.log.2016-04-20_11-36
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     494 Apr 20 11:44 worker.log.2016-04-20_11-44
```

**What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to rotate the logs on a scheduled term even when nothing is being written to the logs?**

Comment: How oft did you call `log.debug('Hello world')`?

Comment: @julivico, The app is full of logs in many places. For each request that comes the app logs approximately 100+ lines of logs in various places. So I guess that depends on how many requests there are in a given period of time. The incoming requests may be 50/second or 1/hour, it's total variable and up to the users.

But I still want the logs to rotate even if there is no activity. Possible?

Comment: If there is no activity, the logging is inactive too.  Because of that, the logs will be not rotated. I think, you won't have this problem with daily rotating. Or you can use `logrotate` on linux system

Comment: I will consider `logrotate` as an alternative... Thanks @julivico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems `TimedRotatingFileHandler` doesn't have the functionality that you need.
You can try the following function for rotating the log files at the certain time.

```
def log_rollover(folder_path):
    # folder_path: the absolute path to your log folder 
    today = str(datetime.date.today()).replace('-', '')
    list_of_files = os.listdir(folder_path)
    for log_file in list_of_files:
        file_path = folder_path + '/' + log_file
        if log_file.endswith('.log') and os.stat(file_path).st_size > 0:
            new_file_path = file_path.split('.')[-2] + '-' + today + '.log'
            subprocess.check_call(['cp', file_path, new_file_path])
            subprocess.check_call(['gzip', new_file_path])
            subprocess.check_call(['cp', '/dev/null', file_path])
```

Also you need to use a cron job to run the function at the certain time.
`APScheduler` can be a good option. For example if you want to run the cron job at 3 AM, you can use:

```
folderPath = '/var/log/app'  # The path to your log folder
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(log_rollover, trigger='cron', args=[folderPath], hour=3, minute=0)
scheduler.start()
```

Don't forget to set your timezone for `APScheduler`.

Comment: Thanks. This seems useful. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and came up with a different approach:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os

def rotate_log_if_new_day(self):
    now = datetime.now().date()
    file_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime("manager.err")).date()
    if file_date != now:
        self.logger.debug("Date changed with no events - rotating the log...")
        self._errhandler.doRollover()
```

`rotate_log_if_new_day()` is called during the manager's update cycle (every 15 minutes) which guarantees the log will rotate within 15 minutes of midnight. If the log has already rotated (ie: an error was logged or it already did the manual rotation), it does nothing.

Originally I had a guard to prevent the `os.path...` call unless the date had changed, but `timeit()` shows a negligible speedup gained by caching the current date (1.85μs vs 5.7μs) to verify no action required.